# Django function based view to class based view

Tags: python, django, class, django-generic-views, create-view

I have this url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/picturelist/1`, which makes user_id = 1,

In my urls.py

```
url(r'^picturelist/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', views.pictureList),
```

In my view.py

```
def pictureList(request, user_id):
    if int(user_id) != request.user.id:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

How can I make this function based view to use createview?

```
class pictureList(CreateView):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this: 

In urls.py: `url(r'^picturelist/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', views.MakeItView.as_view()),`

In views.py:

```
class MakeItView(CreateView):
    model = myModel
    template_name = 'whatever.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MakeItView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if int(self.kwargs['user_id']) != self.request.user.id:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return context
```

Comment: hi I get NoReverseMatch at /author/add/4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438927/noreversematch-django-class-based

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `CreateView`, but here's what I gather from reading the docs:

You could do it by defining [form_valid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid):

**view:**

```
class pictureList(CreateView):
  model = YourModelHere
  fields = ['whatever','fields','you','want','edited']

  def form_valid(self, form):
    record = form.save(commit = False)

    # assuming the user id is associated 
    # to the model with fieldname user_id

    if (self.request.user == record.user_id):
      record.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    # not sure if this works:
    return self.form_invalid()
```

Then the template would be at `'yourappname/yourmodelhere_form.html'`.

See [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) for an example.