# NoReverseMatch django class based

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

edit.

sorry I'm having a hard time and thanks for your help how do I do that?

model

```
   created_by = models.ForeignKey(User) 



   def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author_update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'user_id': self.created_by})
```

Could be related to the error [Type error with django class based view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440891/type-error-with-django-class-based-view)

I get this error

```
NoReverseMatch at /author/add/4
Reverse for 'author_add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['author/add/(?P<user_id>\\d+)$']
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^author/add/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', AuthorCreate.as_view(), name='author_add'),
 url(r'^author/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<pk>\d+)$', AuthorUpdate.as_view(), name='author_update'),
 url(r'^author/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', AuthorDelete.as_view(), name='author_delete'),
 url(r'^author/list/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', AuthorList.as_view(), name='author_list'),
```

views.py for createview

```
class AuthorCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = [ 'firstName', 'lastName', ]
    template_name = 'authorCreate.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('author_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(AuthorCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AuthorCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if int(self.kwargs['user_id']) != self.request.user.id:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return context
```

views.py for listview

```
class AuthorList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'authorList.html'
    queryset = Author.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AuthorList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if int(self.kwargs['user_id']) != self.request.user.id:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return context
```

authorCreate.html

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

authorList.html

```
   {{ request.user.username}} 

    <ul>
        {% for author in object_list %}
            <li>{{ author.firstName }}
                 <a href="{% url "author_update" author.id %}">{{ author.firstName }}</a>
                 <a href="{% url "author_delete" author.id %}">delete</a>
            </li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

terminal error

```
Internal Server Error: /author/add/4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 29, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/vort/larb/views.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 87, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 205, in post
    return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 171, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/vort/larb/views.py", line 82, in form_valid
    return super(AuthorCreate, self).form_valid(form)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 148, in form_valid
    return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 78, in form_valid
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 132, in get_success_url
    if self.success_url:
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 125, in __wrapper__
    res = func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 509, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ronald/best/A2/0124/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 429, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'author_add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['author/add/(?P<user_id>\\d+)$']
```

Comment: Please show the complete templates and urls. For example, you haven't shown the `author_update` URL pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `success_url = reverse_lazy('author_list')` will take you back to the 'author_list' view after success, but in order to go back to 'author_list', you need to provide an argument to the 'user_id' field because in your urls.py you have:

```
url(r'^author/list/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', AuthorList.as_view(), name='author_list'),
```

**Edit:**

remove the `success_url` field and input the following:

```
class AuthorCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = [ 'firstName', 'lastName', ]
    template_name = 'authorCreate.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('author_list', kwargs={'user_id': self.request.user.id})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(AuthorCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AuthorCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if int(self.kwargs['user_id']) != self.request.user.id:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return context
```

Comment: invalid syntax (views.py, line 79)  success_url = reverse_lazy('author_list', kwargs={'user_id': <user_id>})

Comment: you have to replace <user_id> with whatever user id that you wish to use for the url

Comment: sorry I'm having a hard time and thanks for your help how do I do that? model   created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author_update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk, 'user_id': self.created_by})

Comment: asked another question same error different arguments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442797/noreversematch-django-class-based-views