# Type error with django class based view

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I get this error

TypeError at /author/list/4
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Exception Location:     /home/ronald/best/A2/0124/vort/larb/views.py in get_context_data, line 140

```
context = super(AuthorCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

url.py

```
url(r'^author/list/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', AuthorList.as_view(), name='author_list' ),
```

views.py for listview

```
class AuthorList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'authorList.html'
    queryset = Author.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AuthorCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if int(self.kwargs['user_id']) != self.request.user.id:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return context
```

authorList.html

```
   {{ request.user.username}} 

    <ul>
        {% for author in object_list %}
            <li>{{ author.firstName }}
                 <a href="{% url "author_update" author.id %}">{{ author.firstName }}</a>
                 <a href="{% url "author_delete" author.id %}">delete</a>
            </li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code should be this:

```
class AuthorList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'authorList.html'
    queryset = Author.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AuthorList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if int(self.kwargs['user_id']) != self.request.user.id:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return context
```

In context = Super(...).get_context_data, I changed it from AuthorCreate to AuthorList

Comment: I still get an error. NoReverseMatch at /author/list/4

Reverse for 'author_update' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['author/(?P<user_id>\\d+)/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']

Comment: I believe that that problem is unrelated to the problem you've asked in this post. To diagnose the problem more information about it is needed.. such as the code from the views and urls as well as the error stack trace

Comment: I already check your answer if you can help in my other question, thanks.

Comment: I've answered it -- let me know if it helps :)